# Using NodeJS+mySQL to create website. issue checking login entered data with stored values in the DB, then routing user to another page

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using NodeJS+mySQL to create a website. There's an issue checking login entered data with stored values in the DB, then routing the user to another page.

A connection trying to compare database record to the entered values from user in the login page:

```
pool.getConnection(function (error, tempCont) {
  if (!!error) {
    tempCont.release();
    console.log('Error');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Connected!');
    let x = tempCont.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = ${req.body.user_name}', function(err,result,field){
      if (!!error) {
        console.log('Error in user_name Query');
      }
      else {
        console.log(result);
      } 
    });
```

A connection trying to compare database record to the entered values from user in the login page:

```
    let y = tempCont.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` = ${req.body.password}',function(err,result,field){
      if (!!error) {
        console.log('Error in password Query');
      }
      else {
        console.log(result);
      }                
    }); 
    console.log(x.value);
    console.log(y.value);
    if ('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ${req.body.user_name}' && 
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = ${req.body.password}') {
      console.log("success");
      tempCont.release();
    }
    else {
      console.log('Error in the Query');
    }
   }
 })
```

A connection trying to compare database record to the entered values from user in the login page.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You said you have an issue but then forgot to mention what it actually is

Comment: The problem is I can not get a value from DB and compare it with the value entered by the user to check it. Then I should take a decision to route the user to enter the site or to say to him/her sorry you are not a registered user

Comment: why can't you? Which part don't you understand? How to get user input? How to read a value from the database? How to compare values? How do redirect to another URL? What did you try? Each of these steps is a pretty common thing to do, there will be plenty of examples online,

Comment: I succeeded in getting the value from DB using query statement. But I do need to store this value in a variable so I can compare it with the entered value from user. I can not store the value of db in a variable outside the query statement .. This is the problem

Comment: var x = 1;
var y = 0;

 var z =connection.query ('SELECT * from `roles` where `id` = '+x , function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    
    console.log (results[0].role);
   y=results[0].role;
   console.log (y);
   return y;
});
console.log(y);
console.log(z);

Comment: Here z shows object .. while y inside query shows a specific value .. I can not get the specific value outside the query

Comment: ok .. How can do I use promise?